# PostgreSQL/Python: insert new row only if doesn't exists already

Tags: python, postgresql, duplicates

My table:

```
class api(Base):
    __tablename__ = "api"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    gender = Column(String)
    age = Column(String)
    value = Column(Integer)

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

When I send an api query with dates which overlaps with previous queries duplicate rows are created. How can I avoid that? I can delete duplicates but is there a more efficient way to avoid inserting them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `SQLAlchemy` ORM. You can [add `unique=True` to a single column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) to create constraint on your table. For example:

```
class API(Base):
    ...
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

You can also create unique constraint on multiple columns [by passing `UniqueConstraint` to `__table_args__`.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#declarative-table-args) For example:

```
class API(Base):
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('date', 'gender'),
    )
```

It is still recommended that you should check the existence before you inserting the new record into the database, since a violation of database constraint will normally be logged in the database log file.

Comment: I have multiple entries for one date because of different gender and age. So I guess I need to use your second suggestion but adding age there too... I'll try that and come back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the correct approach is the other way round.  You have to try to insert and catch the integrity error when the exception fails. Eliminates the need for two queries and also avoids another thread inserting between your select and insert.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [database constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) that forbids duplicate entries and handle errors in your code.